# Java System.out to both screen and file simultaneously, and programatically

Tags: java

Looking for a way programmatically from Java to send System.out both to a file, and to the screen.

If I were running from a command line, I could for instance run:
java myProgram | tee myProgram.log

This is not, what I am looking for. I need to do this in the Java code itself.

Comment: Use a `Logger` with multiple appenders.

Comment: log4j is a good logger you can use....

Comment: Have a look at `System.setOut` and `System.setErr`.